# Build Phonegap 3.3 project with Android 4.2.2 (API 17)

Tags: android, cordova, build

I have recently updated my phonegao version to 3.3.0 and when I create and build a new project with Phonegap in Android the project builds using my highest Android SDK version (Android 4.4 - API 19 in my case), but I want to build my phonegap 3.3 projects using Android 4.4.2 version (API 17).

Any ideas about how to perform this action?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you do not want API 19 in your project, It means you want your project to run upto android version 4.2.2 only.

Make following changes in your config.xml

```
<preference name= "android-minSdkVersion" value="7"/>
```

if you want restriction on versions then you can include target version as

```
targetSdkVersion="17"
```

if you dont include target version then there will be no restrictions.